# Binding Object to TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hierarchical-data, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to bind my object to a `TreeView`.

I have the following object set up:

```
public class BuildStep
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NodeLevel { get; set; }
    public List<BuildStep> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to bind this data to a TreeView. I read a lot of answers and docs about `HierarchicalDataTemplate` but can't get it to work!

How would I bind this object to the TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView` to an `IEnumerable` of `BuildStep` root nodes:

```
List<BuildStep> rootNodes = new List<BuildStep>() { /* build your list of BuildSteps */ };
treeView.ItemsSource = rootNodes;
```

You can then use an `HierarchicalDataTemplate` like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BuildStep}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeLevel}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

`WpfApplication1` refers to the namespace of the `BuildStep` class.